# Is there a pitch accent difference between the two 〜たって derivations?

Tags: pronunciation, pitch-accent, pitch

In particular say:

- “東京に行ったって言ったの？” => “He said he went to Tokyo?”
- “東京に行ったって何も変わらない” => “Going to Tokyo won't change anything.”

Are these two “〜たって” coming from different sources, one replaceable with “〜たと” the other with “〜ても” pronounced differently in some way, and does the same apply to other verbs too?

Comment: @sundowner I don't see how those are answering whether the “〜たって”form has any pronunciation difference from the past form plus the informal quotative. They simply explain the meaning of that form.

Comment: Re "pronounced differently in some way": I may be wrong but just focusing on たと and ても, I think the accents are the same regardless of the accent type of the preceding verb.

Answer (score 2):

The て in the second sentence is always low. That in the first is also usually low but it may stay high after a flat verb.